# How to display count of notification in app icon in android Programatically

Tags: android

In my android application i am putting notification using firebase,it gives me notification count properly, but now i want to get notification badge in app icon like whatsapp, facebook etc...
Can any one helping me ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Notification badges are automatically added on app icon, if new/unread notification is available. Can't you see it?

Comment: For all device it is not shown

Comment: It's not possible to display for all devices,It's only supported by specific devices

Comment: Which device are you talking about? Can u share screenshot?

Comment: some samsung, sony and htc device support notification counter, not all device supported

Comment: Samsung Galaxy J2 does not show badge on app icon and also some other devices

Answer (score 0):

you can refer about push notification badge [Notification Badge overview](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)